# How can I customize views in django?

Tags: django, django-views

Hi I am learning django from youtube channel.What are these(? mark),is this queryset or varaible.I am totally confused.From where I can find documentation or online resources about this.Please help me.Sorry for my bad English.
[image: views.py]
[image: models.py]

Answer (score 0):

In this `cart` function you're creating a new `Order` object:

- First you get the `customer` from the function parameter (request)
- Then you create a new `Order` object, called order, setting its parameters `customer` (the one we got previously) and `complete` parameter as false. The `created` var tell us if the object was created
- The last var items is a queryset returning all `Order` objects

This is a great tutorial for django beginners: simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/beginners-guide/1.11/